# How to change antd Modal button color

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, simplemodal

I am facing difficulty changing the color of antd Modal buttons
That is the cancel button and ok Button. Can any one tell me how can I do that

Comment: https://ant.design/components/modal/

see the bottom of the page there are properties for cancelbuttonprop and okbuttonprop

Comment: explain briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Modal
  visible={this.state.visible}
  title="Title"
  closable={false}
  footer={null}>
  <div>
    Test For No two buttons on the footer.
    And No One in header.
  </div>
  <div>
    <Button style={{background:'#000000'}} type="ghost" onClick={this.handleClick}>Login</Button>
  </div>
</Modal>
```

Comment: This approach works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the style of buttons via `okButtonProps` and `cancelButtonProps` like:

```
<Modal 
    okButtonProps={{ style: { backgroundColor: 'red' } }} 
    title="Logout" 
    open={isModalOpen} 
    onOk={handleOk} 
    onCancel={handleCancel}
>
    <p>Are you sure you want to logout?</p>
</Modal>
```